# How to edit wordpress pages through cpanel?

Tags: php

Can you visit http://cmscard.com/?page_id=9  in firefox ?
The links are overlapping there.
What to do ?
If core pages or theme need to be edited, where to find the pages ?
The stylesheet is contained in wp-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your provided link there is mistake in your uploaded product images.There is no image in all post/product that's why links are overlapping.

For that whenever you add this all posts/product into wp-admin at that place please select or upload appropriate images or remove this  tag from the specific file. file location is below.

wp-content->themes->your-theme->content.php or in template folder your-template.php

Comment: I've learnt a lesson. Never check in Firefox. Always use google chrome. Chrome shows the webpage as it is....

Comment: One more thing is to mention here...the reason why I'm not finding the wp-content folder is that my manager has given me wrong cpanel...so even this happens in web-developing...lol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I can visit it by firefox. Not the links are overlapping. As there is nothing in the image link "http://cmscard.com/files/wpsc/product_images/thumbnails/about2.jpg". The text between "alt" is overlapping. Make sure that the image link is perfect. Else shorten/delete the text between "alt" tag.

For editing style.css:
 wp-content > themes > theme name > style.css

add this to css style ,

```
div.default_product_display div.textcol div.imagecol a img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Anything concerning the look of wordpress can be corrected within the theme folder. You can find that here:

wp-content-->themes-->theme_name